# Visual Studio Enterprise Library Configuration Addon throws an error

Tags: .net, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-6

Hi I seem to be having some problems with the enterprise library config extension for visual studio 2012.The first time I Installed it everything worked fine and I managed to finish the configurations I needed.

But now when I try to open it I get this error:

[image]

Now I have checked if everything is installed and points to the correct paths in my project csproj and everything should be ok.

I have installed Enterprise Library version 6.

I have also made sure that my Enterprise Library Configuration addon is also version 6.

Is there anything else I could do to make this work?

**EDIT**

I have also tryed to create a new aplication a test the extension and it seems that it works on a new application.It seems to be something related to my curent solution.Anyone have any ideeas why?

Comment: What is the solution property for "Enterprise Library v6 binaries path" set to?

Comment: I am not sure where to check that can you pls tell me?

Comment: In Solution Explorer, click the solution and then press F4 to see the properties window.

Comment: Or you can see it in the solution file: `GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
  EnterpriseLibraryConfigurationToolBinariesPathV6 = packages\EnterpriseLibrary.Common.6.0.1304.0\lib\NET45;packages\EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.6.0.1304.0\lib\NET45
 EndGlobalSection`.